# How does one allow access to networked PCs to see your "localhost" in IIS7 - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, localhost, iis-7, iis-6

I have a computer setup with a `localhost` in IIS, and the computer is visible on an internal network. In Windows XP IIS6, I could just type `http://<computername>/` and I would see that user's `localhost`. In windows 7 IIS7 it seems this is disabled by default. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to use the Control Panel Applet for Windows Firewall.

[image]

[image]

Then click on "inbound rules" and scroll to find the "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-in)" rule.

[image]

Enable it.

done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you developed this using WebMatrix. That installs IIS 7 Express, instead of IIS 7. It happened to me too, and I solved the problem by following the steps here: http://blog.alirobertson.com/post/11139712138/enabling-non-localhost-access-to-webmatrix

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by doing the following:
Enter:
Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall

Click on:
Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall

Please make sure to enable:
World Wide Web Services (HTTP) for Home/Work (Private)

I can now run my localhost webs in Win7 IIS from another PC within the same local network.
Please note that trying to ping the remote PC will not respond unless you open windows firewall and turn off firewall on Home or work (private) network local settings (not recommended)

Regards 
Lars